# RNRF: How open drawer with custom "hamburger?" Not documented in API. Error: "Actions.get" is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using the

```
<Drawer>
```

tag and it works great, but I don't want the default screen layout with the default "hamburger" menu icon at the top-left of the screen.

I've spent hours trying to get my own button to open the drawer.

I've done my research homework:

1. The RNRF API for Drawer doesn't list open/close methods:
   [image]
2. Was happy to find two EXACT issues "How to open Drawer When use a custom icon in Scene" #1101 and "How to customize drawer button" #1078 on GitHub but none of the solutions work--so close but yet so far!

In Button component:

```
onPress={() => {Actions.get('drawer').ref.toggle()}}
```

but get this error:
[image]

Here is my main code:
[image]